# "ReferenceError: angular is not defined" when running a function?

Tags: angularjs

I'm usingAngularJS 1.6

I have a a .JS file called getJSON.js and it has the following code.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "localhost:5000"
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
        console.log($scope.myWelcome)
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
    });
});
```

When I run that script i get

> ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:824:10)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

I don't see a app.js file I see an angular.min.js file

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the Angular 1.6 library in your html.

You can get it from a CDN.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey I see the html code but where is that suppose to go...? each page has its own html and I am just running this function from a seperate javascript file, and want to later call it in a specific webpage, but not sure where I would include that line...?

Comment: Include in the html file which triggers the script in question.